# Covariance and higher-kinded types in Scala 2.12

Tags: scala, covariance, higher-kinded-types, type-alias

The following code

```scala
type Id[+A] = A
type ReprF[A, F[_]] = Unit
type Repr[A] = ReprF[A, Id]
```

does not compile in Scala 2.12, with the error

```
covariant type Id occurs in invariant position in type 
[A]Playground.this.ReprF[A,Playground.this.Id] of type Repr
```

I don't understand why the covariance of `Id` prevents this code to compile.

`ReprF` should not care if `F` is covariant or not, it just needs a type of kind `* -> *`.

Am I missing something?

Curiously it compiles correctly in Scala 2.11.

This is a [scastie snippet](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nicmart/pm2qNdnaRWWW0Y46DQBWRg/1) if you want to play a bit with the code. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think the compiler is very confused by the covariant ID. Even with all being covariant it still gives the same error:

```
trait Test {
  type Id[+A] = A
  type ReprF[+A, +F[+_]] = Unit
  type Repr[+A] = ReprF[A, Id]
}

Error: covariant type Id occurs in invariant position in type [+A]Test.this.ReprF[A,Test.this.Id] of type Repr
  type Repr[+A] = ReprF[A, Id]
```

If I leave the ID undefined, it is fine:

```
trait Test {
  type Id[+A]
  type ReprF[A, F[_]] = Unit
  type Repr[A] = ReprF[A, Id]
}
```

Comment: Yes the example was extracted from a code like you first snippet.
Very interesting and puzzling what you found out with the second one!